# What does HeapValidate in windows do?

Tags: c++, windows

I have been reading up on [HeapValidate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/heapapi/nf-heapapi-heapvalidate) in an existing code and trying to figure out what does it do. The documentation says that it checks whether the heap control structures are in a consistent state. What does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The heap is a data structure like any other, and in its metadata-state-variables there are certain conditions that should always be true.  As a made-up example, the number of children in a heap-tree-node should always be a non-negative number; so if HeapValidate() reads a child-count variable and sees that it is negative, it knows something has gone badly wrong and can flag that block as broken.

You might wonder, assuming Microsoft’s heap code does not have any bugs, how the heap’s metadata might get in to an invalid/“impossible” state like that in the first place.  Since the heap’s metadata structures live in the same address space that the user-code has access to, it’s usually the result of buggy user code writing some other data via an invalid pointer that happens to point at a memory location where the heap’s metadata field happens to reside, silently overwriting/corrupting the metadata.